# Mocking a Uri fails with Can't Find Stub

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-testing, mockk

I have this class that I'm trying to test:

```
class GetNavigationModel @Inject constructor() {

    operator fun invoke(contentResolver: ContentResolver, uuid: String): NavigationModel {

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(
            Models.APPOINTMENT.contentUri,
            arrayOf("one", "two", "three"),
            "one = ?",
            arrayOf(uuid),
            null
        )

        // more stuff follows
    }
}
```

This is my test so far:

```
class GetNavigationModelTest {

    @MockK
    lateinit var mockContentResolver: ContentResolver

    private val useCaseUnderTest = GetNavigationModel()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        mockkStatic(Uri::class)
        val uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse(BASE_URI), UUID)
        every { Models.APPOINTMENT.contentUri } returns uri
    }

    @Test
    fun myTest() {
        useCaseUnderTest.invoke(mockContentResolver, UUID)
        assert(true)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val BASE_URI = "content://com.example.provider"
        private const val UUID = "appointment"
    }
}
```

Where I am stuck is on the line `Models.APPOINTMENT.contentUri`. It fails with this error:

> io.mockk.MockKException: can't find stub Uri(temporary mock)